# Is the geometrical meaning of cup product still valid for subvarieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, schubert-calculus

It is known that cup product is Poincaré dual to the intersection. I'm referring to  the following fact: if $X$ is a closed, oriented smooth manifold and $A, B$ are transverse-intersecting oriented submanifolds of codimension $i, j$ respectively, then

$$[A \cap B]^* = [A]^* \smile [B]^* \in H^{i+j}(X)\space ,$$

where the asterisk denotes Poincaré dual.

My question: is the same true if we take $A, B$ to be transverse-intersecting algebraic varieties? (And does that even make sense? I think that an algebraic subvariety defines an homology class given by the pushforward of the inclusion of the top class, and therefore it makes sense; but correct me if I'm wrong).

For context: I'm studying Schubert calculus, and I want to use this fact when $A, B$ are Schubert varieties, but I think Schubert varieties aren't smooth manifolds in general, since they contain singular points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically the approach via *stratifolds* developed by Kreck; see

> Kreck, Matthias.
>   Differential algebraic topology. 
>   From stratifolds to exotic spheres. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 110. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2010

and

> Bunke, Ulrich; Kreck, Matthias; Schick, Thomas. A geometric description of differential cohomology. Ann. Math. Blaise Pascal  17  (2010),  no. 1, 1–16.